# iPhone GUI like the build-in iPod application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, user-interface, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

Need a GUI with many tabs (TabBarController and UITabBar) and one fullscreen view, e.g. a view with player in the native iPod app. It's possible to show last from any tab.
Currently use last iPhone SDK 3.0.

I tried many approaches, e.g. create Utility and put TabBarController on the flipside, but it throw an exception, because of there is no "plain" UIView on the NIB, except several in a TabBarController.

Comment: So build one. What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, i was completing my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. My investigation is completed.

The best is to create TabBars application and show main independent view as modal using
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
and [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably keep a pointer to the tab bar controller and a separate full-screen view controller in your app delegate.  You'd have to manually implement switching out the tab controller's view and the full-screen controller's view.

Comment: How exactly should I swtich these views? I have an error "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "FlipsideView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'" while trying to load a UIView with Just TabBarController ;(

Comment: Make sure the File Owner in your XIB is set to the correct class (UIViewController or a subclass) and that its `view` outlet is connected to a view.

Comment: 1.Created Utility app. 2.Added a TabBarController to the flipside and added a UIView for each TabBarItem. 3.When FliSideController's View outlet is not set then error: "loaded the 'FlipsideView' nib but the view outlet was not set." 4.If set the View outlet to first UIView then it's shown just that view without any tabs. ||| Please specify what UIView to connect with the oulet?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are doing.  It sounds like you want the flip side controller to BE a tab controller, rather than to _contain_ a tab bar controller.  I would recommend creating the flip side controller in your main window XIB with all the tabs in place.  Each of the tab's views can be loaded from separate XIBs.